# Stata to Pandas: even if there are repeated Value Labels?

Tags: python, pandas, stata, label

I try to open a .dta as DataFrame.
But an Error appears:

> "ValueError: Value labels for column ... are not unique. The repeated labels are:" followed by labels which appear twice in a column.

I know labeling multiple codes with the exact same value label in stata is not clever (not my fault).
After some research I know, pandas will not accept repeated value labels (this IS clever).

But I can't figure out a (good) solution.
Is there:

a. a smooth way to open the data with pandas and just rename the doubles (like "label" to "label(2)") in this process?

here is what the data looks like (value labels in brackets):

```
  | multilabel    
1 | 11 (oneone or twotwo)
2 | 22 (oneone or twotwo)
3 | 33 (other-label-which-is-unique)
```

my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

#followed by any option that delivers this solution:
dataframe = pd.read_stata('file.dta')
```

or

b. a fast an easy way to tell stata: just rename all repeated value labels by "label(2)" instead of "label"?
and yes, the code so far is also rather boring:

```
use "file.dta"

*followed by a loop which finds repeated labels and changes them

save "file.dta", replace
```

And yes, there are to many repeated value labels to go trough it one by one.

And here the Stata-Commands to produce a minimal example:

```
set obs 1
generate var1 = 1 in 1
set obs 2
replace var1 = 2 in 2
set obs 3
replace var1 = 3 in 3
generate var2 = 11 in 1
replace var2 = 22 in 2
replace var2 = 33 in 3
rename var2 multilabel
label define labelrepeat 11 "oneone or twotwo" 22 "oneone or twotwo"
label values multilabel labelrepeat
```

I am happy for each suggestion!

Comment: I don't see a reproducible example here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve gives advice.

Comment: ok, you are right, even if i think in this case it will not help thaat much, having an example-data will create higher quality for everybody. sry.

Comment: I am not a Pandas person, which is where you most need help, but from a Stata end, `decode multilabel, gen(valuelabel)` followed by `label values multilabel` will remove the repetition of value labels which you say is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable with repeated labels, then

```
decode multilabel, gen(valuelabel)
label values multilabel
```

puts the value labels in a string variable and then undoes the association of `multilabel` values and the previously attached value labels. I don't know what else you need to do and thus why you do anything else. You now have the same information as before. I don't know whether pandas will ignore the definition of value labels.

For completeness, here's a way to find out which variables have value labels that aren't in one-to-one correspondence with numeric values.

```
* your sandbox, simplified and extended  
clear 
set obs 3
generate var1 = _n 
generate multilabel = 11 * _n
label define labelrepeat 11 "oneone or twotwo" 22 "oneone or twotwo"
label values multilabel labelrepeat

label define var1 1 "frog" 2 "toad" 3 "newt"
label val var1 var1 


* my code 
local bad 
ds *, has(vallabel) 

quietly foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    tempvar decoded diff 
    decode `v', gen(`decoded') 
    bysort `decoded' (`v') : gen `diff' = `v'[1] != `v'[_N] & !missing(`decoded') 
    count if `diff' 
    if r(N) > 0 local bad `bad' `v' 
    drop `decoded' `diff' 
} 

di "`bad'"
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, i marked this as best solution so far. But i have a dataset with more than 1000 variables, and i am not sure if it is effective to generate for each of these variables an additional variable containing the value labels, just to transfer them to pandas, where i am (till now) not able to reattach them to theier variables. Thats why i want to change the value labels: 11 could be labeld "oneone" and 22 could be labeld "twotwo" or (as in my example) 11 could be labeld "oneone or twowo(1)" and 22 could be labed "onone or twotwo(2)".

Comment: `help numlabel` for a way to disambiguate.

Comment: perfect, i should have used the word "disambiguate" instead of talking of "no repeatet value labels" ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since at least pandas 0.22, you can pass `convert_categoricals=False` to `read_stata` and it will not attempt to map the numerical values to their definitions.

`d = pd.read_stata('fooy_labels.dta', convert_categoricals=False)`

Your resulting DataFrame will have the numerical values in the problem column. You can now recode them as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

My final Solution (in Stata):

```
clear

use "file.dta"

*Find out which duplicated value labels there are
labelbook, length(12)

return list, all

*r(nuniq) contains the not-unique-values

*on all variables in r(nuniq) use the numlabels command

numlabel `r(nuniq)', add

*Look at the not unique value labels again:
labelbook, length(12)

return list, all

save "file2.dta", replace
```

Thank you Nick!